# Using canvas draw or another library in Lua, how can I get the width of a string in a certain font on demand?

Tags: user-interface, lua, iup

I want to have a function that, given a string, returns the width of that string in a certain font. Canvas draw has something like this, but I've only been able to set the font and get the width of a string in it in the draw function; not on demand.

Comment: The size of the string depends on the context. So you need a canvas of a certain type to be able to get its size. Once you create a canvas you  can set the font and retrieve the size how many times you want.

What do you mean by "on demand"?

Comment: Whenever I want to, not just when the canvas updates.

Comment: You don't need to way for the draw function. The CD canvas can be created and used anytime (If it is a canvas for a window, the window must exist.)